# java lang Verify Error making request on android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, signpost

I'm trying to make a request to a RESTful API  from an android app using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to make the request, [signpost](https://github.com/mttkay/signpost) to authenticate and [retrofit-signpost](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/signpost-retrofit) to connect the two but I'm getting this error on the request:

`java.lang.VerifyError: com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$AbstractSource`

Any idea why this might be?

EDIT:
Logcat Error log:

`07-02 09:15:30.626  28584-29830/com.example E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'okio.ForwardingTimeout', referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$AbstractSource.<init>`

Comment: There should be more detail in the logcat output; if so, please include it in your question.

Comment: @fadden there.. Added the only error log line I get .

Comment: @fadden I think I found something.. The ForwardingTimeout class is not in the package I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using an outdated version of okio that didn't include the needed class. Just downloaded the latest one from [square/okio's github site](https://github.com/square/okio) and it worked.